# How to find out the location where a unix command executes from?

Tags: unix, command, exec

Is there any way or command to find out the path from where the a standard command is executed from? Example `ls`, `mkdir`, `mysql`, `hadoop`, etc..

I know that their origin can be found out from `$PATH` variable, and should be probably in one of the `/bin` directories. But how can I get the directory correctly from where the command runs from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `which` command returns the full path of an executable, e.g.:

```
mureinik@comupter ~ $ which mkdir
/usr/bin/mkdir
```

and if you really need the directory, you could always apply `dirname` to it:

```
mureinik@conmputer ~ $ dirname `which mkdir`
/usr/bin
```

Comment: Thanks Mureinik, for the quick answer.. :)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to vote up, but it gave me a -1 and I am not able to rollback, it says I need 15 reputation. I found your answer useful, hence requesting the stackoverflow team to remove the -1 and change it to +1

Comment: @anna If this solved your question, you can mark the answer as accepted (the check mark underneath) the voting button.

Comment: @anna you should no have enough reputation to remove the downvote and add an upvote if this answer really helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the OP's question, I noticed the pointed exclusion of methods relying on `PATH`, and disregarded the obvious answer for `which` (because that is precisely what it does).  The `which` program, by the way was originally a C-shell script although there are other implementations ([FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=which&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html), and [bash](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which) for instance).  [Solaris](http://www.manpages.info/sunos/which.1.html), for instance, has a version little changed from [4.2BSD](http://modman.unixdev.net/?sektion=1&page=which&manpath=4.2BSD), and its manual page states

> Both aliases and path are taken from the user's .cshrc file.

If you do not use C-shell, that original version of `which` has limited usefulness.  Because there is no standard version, the results (and capability of the tool) can vary from system to system.  Some shells (such as `ksh`) have similar features, but named differently, e.g., `whence` in the case of `ksh` (bash supplies the ksh alias `type` but not the `whence keyword).

I do not use `which` much, having better tools ([conflict](http://invisible-island.net/conflict/conflict.html) and [path](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:path)).  But having ignored the obvious, the question as worded could easily pose a more interesting question: how can an application determine the directory from which another application was run.  Not the obvious *"where is the executable?"*, but *"what was the working directory when the program was run?"*.  There was a similar question recently dealing with relative pathnames.

On some of the systems which support the `/proc` pseudo-filesystem, there is a `cwd` node which gives the current working directory of a given process.  The question *[Find out current working directory of a running process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94357/find-out-current-working-directory-of-a-running-process)* goes into some detail regarding this.

xterm's optional feature "spawn-new-terminal" (added in [patch #225](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_225) in 2007) uses this information to make a new terminal instance run in the same working directory as the user's current *shell* working directory.

A script could use this by starting with the process-id for the command in question, and inspecting the `/proc` tree for the corresponding `cwd` node.